# .map returned JSON into React JS Components State

Tags: json, dictionary, reactjs

I am trying to set the response of my 'apiRequest' into the Characters components state. I have got as far as logging the returned Json but am having trouble working out how to .map the response.results into State.

If someone could help point me in the right direction I would appreciate it, React sure has a steep learning curve to get over!

**React Component**

```
class Characters extends React.Component {

  apiRequest() {
    request('http://localhost:3000/api', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var swapiRes = body
          console.log(swapiRes)
      }
    })
  }

    render() {
        return (
            <section id="character">
      {this.apiRequest()}
                <div className="container">
                </div>
            </section>
        )
    }
}
```

**Returned JSON**

```
{
    "count":87,
    "next":"http://swapi.co/api/people/?page=2",
    "previous":null,
    "results":
    [
        {
            "name":"Luke Skywalker",
            "gender":"male"
        },      
        {
            "name":"Han Solo",
            "gender":"male"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the state for recalled the render method again

like

```
getInitialState:function()
  {
    return{
      results:[]
    }
  },
```

Now you can set the state once your api response come

```
apiRequest() {
    request('http://localhost:3000/api', function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
          var swapiRes = body
          console.log(swapiRes)
          var res=JSON.Parse(JSON.stringify(response));
          this.setState({results:res.results});
      }
    }.bind(this))
  }
```

Comment: This makes sense now, However I receive a Uncaught TypeError: JSON.Parse is not a function with your example code

Comment: it's a typo you can use json.parse small p in parse  :)

Comment: @James: you get the result array in body ?

Comment: Seem so, If I use .stringify(body) then I get all results into State, however if I change this to body.results OR response.results my State is not updated.

I tried with updated answer, still no State